# An alias (defined as a hosts entry) for a fileserver works only when it is a win2008-box, why?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, hosts

On a Terminalserver (win2008), we like to have an alias for the real fileservername and therefor we put a line in **hosts** like:

- 192.168.0.10    BigFiler

This only works fine for Fileserver under windows 2008 **not for win2003-servers**, why?

We do not have defined a CNAME alias that is created in the DNS zone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more details in your question, I'm assuming you have this issue:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281308

Which basically means that the W2K3 server isn't listening for requests to the alias name.

Comment: We do not have defined a CNAME alias that is created in the DNS zone! There is only a hosts entry on the client computer from were we want to access the fileserver.
The kb281308 doesn't apply to this issue, i think.

Comment: It does. It doesn't matter whether you have a CNAME record in your DNS zone or an entry in your hosts file. The file server doesn't know that it should respond to the name in the hosts file. 1. The file server has a computer name, let's call it Filer. 2. On the terminal server you have an entry for Filer called BigFiler. 3. Filer doesn't respond to the name BigFiler because it doesn't know that it should. 4. Follow the KB article to make Filer listen for requests to the name BigFiler. 5. Test.

Comment: ok, but the terminalserver converts any access to BigFiler to the IP-Address of Filer as defined in his hosts-file, or not?

Comment: At the network layer yes, but at the application layer the request is still going to the "alias" name, which the server won't respond to, unless you follow the steps in the KB.